# Ember Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, view, extend

the error is Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined,my ember is the newest,and  i need some help,please.
[enter image description here][1]

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
   templateName : 'application1'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ember 2.x Views are removed from the API. Check this link for more information http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view.

If you still want to use Views you can install `ember-legacy-views` addon  https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-views.